# What is the difference between the Morgana and Aigis covers for the Persona 3/5 Dancing games?

Tags: version-differences, persona-3-dancing-in-moonlight, persona-5-dancing-in-starlight

When I was out looking for what to get for Christmas i saw the Persona 3/5 dancing game on the shelves but to my surprise there was 2 with different covers, one blue one with an Aigis Logo and one red one with a Morgana Logo.

from my understanding they are separate games as opposed to just different covers so i could assume you only play as SEES and the Phantom Thieves of Hearts respectfully but is that the only difference between the games? just who you play as?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, same game. The only difference is the characters and soundtrack (from each game respectively) - even the story is the same.

You can also pick up the bundled version of both games which comes with the Persona 4 version which is basically the prequel.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you implying that the music is the same as well?

Comment: @ChaseIngebritson I didn't mean to imply that, but it looks like I was. I edited my answer to also state the music is different.